# UrlFetchApp Fetch method doesnt return

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a very simple google api script :

```
function callNasdaqOMX() {
  
  // Call the Nasdaq OMX for AAK

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx?SubSystem=Prices&Action=GetInstrument&Source=OMX&Instrument=SSE36273");
  
}
```

However, the response is never returned. The link is quick. If you put the url in a browser, you will get a xml answer immediately.

Has anyone any idea ?

Comment: It is just stuck at "Execution started"

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I'm seeing similar, and not sure how to troubleshoot it.